# A concise template for homework questions

Tags: discussion

**TL;DR**: A maniacal plan to boost my rep. If it is too long for you, then you probably have been here long enough and don't need to read it.

This is just a post seeking to make newer users think a bit more about posting a homework question:

At times, there are these very deep questions posted by absolutely new users.

> Calculate the molality of a 5 M solution of H2SO4 having density 1.15 g/ml.

Nothing more, nothing less. Just the problem statement and the expectation of a homework question solved with no actual effort from the side of the OP to learn [Most of the time]. Most of these users go missing for months seeing no solution each time they appear. The regular users end up with a bad feeling as well since the question ends up unformatted and unwanted by all involved. Lose-Lose. The question ends up closed.

Now, there are a few users who do the formatting, but the whole issue lies in the fact that new users treat this space like any other - Quora (Where only the title matters), Yahoo Answers [do people use this still though].

Chem.SE was built to be unlike the others [insert question stating this in an answer].

I propose to create a homework template for homework [this just means problems]

```
### Question

> [Insert the question here]

### Answer

>! [Answer provided in the manual. If no answer exists, then state so and move on]

### My attempt

[Add what you have done so far, and state **what concept or at what part** you are unable to proceed]

[Thanks/Sorry and other salutations are not required]
```

The final part is of the utmost importance as that what shows the others whether you are cheating by leaching onto others or not.

So the question posted above becomes, assuming you are a completely new user who used this template:

---

#### Question

> Calculate the molality of a 5 M solution of H2SO4 having density 1.15 g/ml.

#### Answer

> 8

#### My attempt

I know that molality is number of moles of solute divided by the weight of solvent in kg and density is mass divided by volume. But how do we relate molarity with molality even with these parameters given?

---

Even if the user had not spent much time with attempting the question, This atleast shows that they have spent some effort in making it presentable. After which the regulars users instead of spending effort in answering can use the comments to answer the OP's problem. Win-Win for both. In the end, someone desperately wanting reputation can answer the question and give it the answered. This gets the question answered in the long run and everyone wins.

Comment: How would you propose to "enforce" it, or in more realistic wording, how do you propose to make new users aware of this and get them to format their question in such a manner?

Comment: This is a great idea, just a couple of things to keep in mind. First, from my experience, only about half of the "HW" questions could be put comfortably in this template. Some questions are so poorly formulated or lack details that they couldn't be squeezed in any template no matter how many there were. I probably wouldn't *enforce* this, but it can definitely be a useful suggestion for the new user base. Second, do keep in mind that massive editing of HW-alike question would bring a tidal wave of what is mostly boring or trivial stuff for many advanced users to the main page.

Comment: Also, I suppose you are about to reach an [edit cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) pretty soon. A user with over 2000 rep points does *not* receive +2 for approved edits anymore.

Comment: @Orthocresol As normal, we close it and ask them to read this and just fill out the template if they require re-opening. The effort involved would be lower since they just have to fill in the blanks. It takes time, but if it doesn't then there is no point asking here.

Comment: @andselisk Then that foils my entire rep cap idea... But it still prettifies the site.. Also, we do it for the newer questions and not the old ones. The OP themselves has to do it.

Comment: @andselisk if you do not have enough details to substantiate what you need to know, then there is no point in asking the question here, is there? If it stays like this for 3 days, it means that nobody needs it and so can be pushed to delete [which would take too long for me to reach at this pace, 10000 is steep]

Comment: @Safdar Yes, pretty much so, if one would look at that logically. By the way, thank you for being so enthusiastic. Despite you being a relatively new user, your edits are well done and really help (less work for mods, too). Just make sure not to burn out too soon;)

Comment: Thank you for attempting this. To be honest though: I am not a big fan of this structure of the post and I have regularly removed it in the past. There is nothing more concise than the exercise quoted in full as a blockquote, and below that any context explaining the problem with this exercise. However, sometimes a guiding structure can help especially new users to fix up their post, so I really have nothing against doing it that way either.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン It doesn't work though. 90% of posts do not even have the data to fill this up and so they do not change. Formatting by the regular users breaks the purpose of this post.

Comment: After reading it I still don't get your idea...  And really, homework dumps are such a waste of time of users that I don't how anyone wins in any case.